How to convert output audio to input audio using Python
I am currently recording my computer's microphone using pyaudio (and later creating a transcript for this audio using Google Cloud speech). This is my current code for recording the microphone:
# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)  # 100ms

class MicrophoneStream:
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""
    def __init__(self, rate, chunk):
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self):
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            rate=self._rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            # Stream callback for asynchronous audio processing
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
            input_device_index=1,
        )
        self.closed = False
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream into the buffer."""
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self):
        """Generates audio chunks from the buffer."""
        while not self.closed:
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            yield chunk

What I am trying to do is instead of recording my computer's microphone, I want to record the output audio, such as audio from videos I'm watching. If possible, I don't want to use any 3rd party programs for this. Thank you for the help in advance.

Does this answer your question? Record speakers output with PyAudio

If you have a virtual device called Digital Stereo Mix (depends of the audio manufacturer), you can use it as the input input_device_index. You can list all your input devices, as seen by PyAudio with :
def print_input_devices():
  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
  print("  Audio host API:", p.get_default_host_api_info()['name'])
  print("  Default input device :")
  print(p.get_default_input_device_info())
  print("  Other available input devices :")
  info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
  for i in range(info.get('deviceCount')):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
      print(p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i))

The input device I use to record YouTube etc is n°2 named "Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)"
